# Дублирование комментария при попытке сделать ответ на комментарий

Tags: javascript, php

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой что когда пытаюсь сделать ответ на определенный комментарий, происходит дублирование всех комментариев и при этом в базе данных не отображается дублирование комментариев а только на странице. Такое чувство что при отправке комментария отправляеться не только один коммент а какие то еще хотя вроде бы запрос в БД сделан правильно + выведение информации так же: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь Php code:

```
<?php foreach ($showcomn as $result){?>

         <?php foreach ($showreplycom as $resultreply){?>

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['all-good'])) {

            echo '<p id="user-comment-info">'.$result['name'].' '.$result['date'].'<br></p>',
            '<div id="comment-user">',
                '<p id="stealth-'.$result['id'].'">'.$result['comment'].'</p>',
            '</div>',


             '<form method="post" action="./check%20info/editsavechanges.php">';
        if ($findid['id'] === $result['userID']){
               echo '<textarea id="id-edit-save-'.$result['id'] .'" name="id-each-user" hidden>'.$result['id'].'</textarea>',
                '<textarea name="edit-comment"  id="edit-user-comment-'.$result['id'].'" class="edit-style" hidden >'.$result['comment'].'</textarea>',

            '<div id="buttons-edit">',
                '<button type="submit"  name="save-edit-comment"  id="save-edit-user-comment-'.$result['id'].'" hidden>Save</button>',
                '<button type="button" onclick="cancelEdit('.$result['id'].')" id="cancel-edit-user-comment-'.$result['id'] .'" hidden>Cancel</button>',
            '</div>',

                    '<div id="buttons-forms">',
                '<button type="button"  onclick="showForm('.$result['id'].')" id="open-edit-'.$result['id'].'" >Edit</button>',
                '<button type="submit"  name="delete-edit-comment" id="delete-edit-'.$result['id'].'" >Delete</button>',
            '</div>';
        }
                 echo '<div id="buttons-forms-reply">',
                     '<button type="button"  onclick="showformReply('.$result['id'].')" id="reply-edit-'.$result['id'].'" >Reply</button>',
                     '</div>',

                '<textarea name="reply-userid"  id="comment-userid-reply" class="edit-style-user-id" readonly hidden>'.$findid['id'].'</textarea>',
                '<textarea name="reply-user-name"  id="comment-name-reply" class="edit-style-user" readonly hidden>'. $_SESSION['all-good']['login'] .'</textarea>',


                     '<textarea id="reply-save-comment'.$result['id'] .'" name="reply-comment-id" hidden>'.$result['id'].'</textarea>',
                '<input type="hidden" name="reply-user-date">',

                '<textarea name="reply-comment"  id="reply-text-'.$result['id'].'" class="edit-style-reply" hidden ></textarea>',

            '<div id="reply-buttons">',
                '<button type="submit" name="save-reply-comment"  id="save-reply-edit-'.$result['id'] .'" hidden>Save</button>',
                '<button type="button" onclick="cancelReply('.$result['id'].')" id="cancel-reply-edit-'.$result['id'] .'" hidden>Cancel</button>','<br>',
                '</div>';


            echo '<div id="show-comments-reply">',
                '<button type="button" onclick="showallReply(' . $resultreply['id'] . ')" id="show-reply-all-' . $resultreply['id'] . '" class="all_reply_button">Show all comments</button>',
                '<button type="button" onclick="closeallReply(' . $resultreply['id'] . ')" id="close-reply-all-' . $resultreply['id'] . '" class="close_reply_button" hidden>Close all comments</button>',
            '</div>',
            '<div id="new_box_reply">',
                '<p id="all-reply-com-' . $resultreply['id'] . '" class="reply_box" hidden>' . $resultreply['name'] . ' ' . $resultreply['date'] . '<br>' . $resultreply['comment'] . '</p>',
            '</div>',

            '</form>';
```

Здесь реализация reply формы:

```
<?php include_once "../connection/coments_connection.php";   
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');

if (isset($_POST['save-reply-comment'])) { $commentID = $_POST['reply-comment-id'];
$name = $_POST['reply-user-name'];
$userID = $_POST['reply-userid'];
$comment = $_POST['reply-comment'];
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$replyBase = "INSERT INTO `replycom`(`commentID`, `name`, `comment`, `date`, `userID`) VALUES ('$commentID', '$name', '$comment', '$data', '$userID')";
$resultReply = $Gcom->prepare($replyBase);
$resultReply->execute([
    'reply-comment-id' => $commentID,
    'user-name' => $name,
    'reply-comment' => $comment,
    'reply-user-date' => $data,
    'reply-userid' => $userID,
]);
header('Location: ../index.php#contacts'); }
```

Здесь цикл Foreach для основных комментов:

```
<?php
include_once "./connection/coments_connection.php";
$showcomn = $Gcom->query("SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY date DESC ");
$showcomn = $showcomn->fetchAll();
```

Здесь цикл Foreach для reply комментов:

```
<?php
include_once "./connection/coments_connection.php";
$showreplycom = $Gcom->query("SELECT * FROM `replycom` ORDER BY date DESC ");
$showreplycom = $showreplycom->fetchAll();
```

Comment: нужно вынести все `echo $result ...` из цикла `<?php foreach ($showreplycom as $resultreply){?>`

Comment: Доброго времени суток, спасибо за идею но к сожалению не сработала, убрал все echo и в итоге просто пустая форма без комментариев и кнопок, просто рамка